# Finding the cause for bad XSLT performance in Lucee

Tags: java, xml, xslt, coldfusion, lucee

We're struggling to find the cause for XSL transformations that perform really bad occasionally for quite some time now.

So far there's nothing we can make out as a real cause, since it can occur under heavy load but also when the server is basically idle. The attached example happened when there were 158 requests in 15 minutes. So, no mentionable load at all.

We were suspecting some external XML documents that are used within the transformations, but that doesn't seem to be the problem either, since they usually load within milliseconds, sometimes maybe seconds, but nothing that would explain the 200+ seconds the requests took.

The same transformations run quite well when we try them later to check if there's a problem.

We are running Fusion Reactor to monitor our server but there's nothing unusual to see as well. In yesterday's cases, there was neither high CPU load nor anything else out of the ordinary.

I attached a screenshot from Fusion Reactor's profiler, where you can see the times taken and it always seems to be the "scanDocument" part that takes up 99.x% of the time, if we interpret the result correctly.

Is there any way to find out what's causing the delay here?

The versions we are currently running are:

Ubuntu: 14.04.5 LTS
Java: 1.8.0_45
Lucee: 4.5.4.017 final

[image: Fusion Reactor profiler]

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is `99.8%` in `SocketInputStream.sockerRead0` so I'd blame a slow network connection.

The rest of the program is just waiting for bytes to arrive over the slow network connection, so you don't see high CPU

Comment: Hmm, that would sound like our initial suspicion, but we can't see any slow outgoing requests around that time. We are running squid as a proxy that logs all non-https requests and the transformations in question do not have any https-documents included that we would not see.

Could this also be some internal communication problem inside Lucee or Java?

Comment: @korguell:  Why don't you run an experiment with local copies of all needed XML and XSLT files?

Comment: @korguell the slowness is on the incoming stream I suspect, maybe you can run wireshark or some UL/DL speed meter tooling to monitor you networkconnection?

Comment: Problems like this are often caused by requests to fetch well-known DTDs or schemas from the W3C site. W3C deliberately throttle these requests to discourage the practice.